# iPhone OTA update: How to get hidden space back?

Tags: iphone, upgrade, software-update

I've downloaded iOS8 and updated to each version up to 8.1.
However, the disk-space on my iPhone is shrinking and shrinking with this OTA update.

Is there any way to get space back without having to restore it via iTunes? The iOS8 installer is already removed but the free disk space keeps shrinking after each update because it keeps some (hidden) trash on the iPhone.

Comment: I had a device running beta versions of the iOS where messages would download a ton of data. Luckily on 8.1 you can start influencing the "hidden" storage of things like Mail and Messages. First off, what does the usage show as the largest 3 bins of data? What are the exact values of Used and Available on the storage for your device according to the 8.1 settings app?

Comment: @bmike That would be 1) TomTom (1.9GB), 2) Camera and photo's 1.6GB  and 3) Spotify 1.6GB - followed by Angry Birds @ 218MB